# Outlook e-mail autocorrect doesn't let me add Formatted text (grayed out)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

[image]

In the above dialog (Outlook 2010) the text type is a fixed "Plain text" and grayed out, so I can't select the "Formatted text" I need to insert a smiley bitmap.
How can I enable the text type?

**edit**
I retried with "Always check spelling before sending" checked, and now I can select "Formatted text", but I can't enter anything in the field, not even plain text. When I select "Plain text" the field is editable. (The "Always check spelling..." doesn't seem to be required, though, so it seems to be a fluke/bug.)

How can I enter formatted text or images?

**edit 2**
Tried in Outlook 2013. Same problem.

Comment: Since Outlook uses Word as its base editor, have you tried making these changes from Word Auto-correct options (rather than from within Outlook)?

Comment: @CharlieRB: I didn't know it uses Word, but it seems it doesn't share the options: the autocorrect list is different in Word. Also, the same problem in Word: I can't select "Formatted text".

Comment: Well, it was worth a try. Sorry it didn't help. Maybe this indicates a higher level issue with Office, not just Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer [here](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/autocorrect-and-text-formatting-support):

> ...you’ll have to format and select the entry within a message. This selection is then automatically added to the AutoCorrect dialog including its formatting.

1. Create a new email message with the desired formatting, image etc.
2. **Select** the relevant text block (or the entire message, with `ctrl`+ `A`)
3. Open the AutoCorrect dialog *from within the message window*: `File -> Options -> Mail -> Spelling and AutoCorrect... -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options...`
4. The text you selected before will appear (formatted ) in the `With:` text box.

[image: AutoCorrect with formatting (credit: MSOutlook.info)]

Answer (score -1):

Using *"plain text*", You can not format the text. You can only attach files separately, and the text has to be unmodified. (no coloring, no text type, no underline/bold/italic, etc.)

You need to switch to RTF "*Rich Text*" in order to be able to insert images directly into the text, or format the text.

In "*HTML*", You can also do some nice text formatting, but you can only attach files/pictures separately.

Comment: Not helpful. I *know* what "plain text" means. And RTF and HTML can be selected for e-mails, but not in the dialog shown.

Comment: This is an answer to a completely different question from what was asked. It contains accurate information, but is irrelevant to the question being asked.